# Show seconds in chat timestamp titles

Tags: feature-request, chat, timestamps

I just noticed when looking at a message's details, that chat timestamps only show `hh:mm`:

[image]

Could "seconds" be added to that `title`?

Comment: Couldn't agree more.

Comment: Why? What broke your workflow that you need that kind of precision?

Comment: There were some worries of a user not spending any time reviewing a link a bot posted, before responding to the bot. Seconds in timestamps would have easily resolved that.

Comment: Did you try raising your doubts with the user involved? This is such a corner-case to spend dev time on.

Comment: Not my doubts. I was trying to explain that the user had plenty of time to review the link. I don't think _"Dev time"_ is a good argument not to implement it. This can't possibly be more than a simple template edit.

Comment: Ok, I just checked the /events endpoint and the timestamp is there so we could create a userscript until this gets implemented.

Comment: @rene What's the `/events` endpoint?

Comment: @muru That is  this one: `http://chat.stackoverflow.com/chats/41570/events`  where you can POST to with this data `since=0&mode=Messages&msgCount=100&fkey=YOUROWNFKEY` to get chat message as the response.  You can find it working in [this script of mine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/267313/158100)